# why is the object and the curve not aligned?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have been trying to solve this issue but I'm unable to solve it. I don't understand why it's already offset. I'm new to blender so maybe it's a setting problem but I have checked everything.[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the curve modifier.

Comment: When you use the _Curve_ modifier, the origin of your object jumps to the first point of the curve. The object is deformed along the curve down the axis you specify in the modifier.